# How can I create a named route that includes query parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a route to match this:

> /en/companies/:id/settings

But I want a named route to generate this path:

> /en/companies/:id/settings?setting=resources

I have some JS that picks up the parameter at the end. I was hopping to create a path I can use in my code like this:

> resources_settings_company_path

For now I've been doing this:

> settings_company_path(id) + "?setting=resources"

I've looked in advances routing but there doesn't seem to be anything to help me in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
settings_company_path(id, setting: 'resources')
```

This has the same effect as

```
settings_company_path(id) + "?setting=resources"
```

but you can easily add more parameters without messing with `&`, `?`. Also you don't have to worry about parameter encoding.